# Can Meteor child templates access parent template helpers?

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js

Say we have a parent template and a child template:

```
<template name="parent">
  {{> child }}
</template>

<template name="child">
  {{#if show}}
    //Do something
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

If we assign 'show' to the parent template:

```
if (Meteor.isClient){
   Template.parent.show = function(){
     return Session.get('isShowing');
   }
}
```

Is there any way for the child template to have access to it?

Comment: I'd say this is more of a handlebars question

Comment: Handlebars supports ‘../`, but I'm not sure how far back it will go

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Edit**

You could make a universal handlebars helper so you could use Sessions values anywhere in your html:

**Client js**

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('session', function(key) {
    return Session.get(key);
});
```

**Client HTML**

```
<template name="child">
  {{#if session "show"}}
    //Do something
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

Similarly, you could also use `{{session "show"}}` / `{{#if session "show"}}` in your parent template and not have to use the `Template.parent.show` helper anymore.

Regarding the use of `../` notation. There are certain scenarios it may not work: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/563. Basically it works within {{#block helpers}} but not with templates, but it would work in a block helper if it contains a subtemplate.

```
<template name="child">
    {{#if ../show}}
       Do something
    {{/if}}
</template>
```

Comment: I'm seeing this in the handlebars documentation however are you able to reproduce this in Meteor? When I try I'm getting an error in the console: "Uncaught Error: Too many '..' segments". As far as I understand it ../ references the parent context of the data  we are working with so if we had: context = {name: John, posts: {post1: body1, post2: body2}} and we were looping over the posts property we could use ../ to get access to the name property. But I don't think we can use ../ to get access to entirely new data objects we're not already accessing, or at least I can't make it work.

Comment: Yes you are right, It looks like the `../` notation wont necessarily always work with subtemplates. Ive updated the answer with another solution

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Not exactly what I was hoping for (the ../show would be perfect if it worked) but I think this is a useful and fairly clean work around.

Comment: It's so strange that one can access parent contexts in handlebars but not in helpers/programmatically otherwise. Do you know if this has changed?

Answer (score 2):

You can also register a common helper :

```
Template.registerHelper('isTrue', function(boolean) {
    return boolean == "true";
});
```

And call it just like that in your html:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="{{isTrue attr}}"/>
```