# How do I pass dynamic variables into templates in Meteor?

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js

Using data of the form:

```
users = 
  _id: 'foo'
  books: [
    {name: 'book1'}
    {name: 'book2'}
  ]
```

```
<template name="user">
  {{#each get_users}}
    {{> shelf}}
  {{/each}}
</template>

<template name="shelf">
  {{#each books}}
    {{> book}}
  {{/each}}
</template>

<template name="book">
  <div contenteditable="true" data-id="{{_id}}">{{name}}</div>
</template>
```

I want `_id` in the `book` template to refer to the `_id` of the user, but `_id` is not in scope inside the `book` template. I'd like to be able to do something like `{{> book _id}}`, but that doesn't work, I think because `book` can only have one argument, and that is each `{name: 'book1'}` doc.

Comment: Have you attempted `../_id`?  Discussion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15127121/can-meteor-sub-templates-access-parent-template-data).

Comment: ../_id  doesn't work in this example.

Comment: You can define your own handlebars helpers where you can do what you want, for example pass book _id and attach additional info by that _id or else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a custom block helper. It would be nicer if Meteor allowed multiple arguments for custom block helpers (this is supported in Handlebars). Since it doesn't (see the [the wiki](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Handlebars#block-helpers)), this is the best I came up with, passing a modified `this` to the subtemplate `book`.

```
<template name="shelf">
  {{#my_iterator}}
    {{> book}}
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

```
Templates.shelf.my_iterator = (options) ->
  html = "
  for book in this.books
    this.name = book.name
    html += options.fn this
  html
```